# Framework for user defined relationships

Tags: python, django

I'm thinking about creating a Django-powered website where users would be able to relate entities to each other. Examples would for instance include: "John is married to Mary" or "John works at Google".

Users should be able to define the entities and their relationships themselves (and will typically define relations of *other* people, not of themselves). Ideally, users enter these relations as free text (where subject and object could perhaps be an autocomplete field, based on previously entered existing entities).

Django's model framework is ideal for storing the entities and their relations, but how would one make such a thing manageable on a higher level?

Is there a Python-powered ontological framework (thanks duffymo) that would help me derive structure out of these user-generated relationships? I'm looking for ways to for example derive reversible relations, aggregate relations (e.g. "3 persons are family relations of John"), classify into types of relations (family relations, work relations, ...), and this all based on user generated input and not a (known) predefined set of relations. It

Thanks in advance,

Mathieu

Comment: "my question is not really about..." Isn't the best way to ask a question.  Please **update** your question to state what it **is** about from the very beginning.  There are an infinite number of things your question is not about.  There are very few things it is about.  Feel free to revise it to be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/), the Stanford ontology program.  If you can run it for Java, perhaps you can run it for Jython.

http://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2004/slides/3.3_dameron_7-7-04.pdf

Comment: Interesting pointer; I'm off hunting for Python powered ontology frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

> Users are able to define the relationships themselves (and will typically define relations of other people, not of themselves);

Fine.

> there is in other words no pre-defined set of possible relations.

So?  This isn't an interesting constraint.  Why mention it?

> Ideally, users enter these relations as free text (where subject and object could perhaps be an autocomplete field).

Fine.

```
 class Person( models.Model ):
     # whatever

 class RelatedTo( models.Model ):
     one_person= models.ForeignKey( Person, related_name="me" )
     other_person= models.ForeignKey( Person, related_name="them" )
     relationship = models.TextField( )
```

That's one way to do it.  It's not difficult if you make the "relationship" a first-class object.

If you want multi-party relationships, it works like this.

```
 class Person( models.Model ):
     # whatever

 class RelatedTo( models.Model ):
     relationship_type = models.TextField( )

 class Party( models.Model ):
     relationship = ForeignKeyField( RelatedTo )
     role = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I should have mentioned that I've got enough Django "in my fingers" to be able to work out a model layout. I would by the way opt for generic relations anyway (http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/). My question is more in the line of: how would you make such a thing manageable and e.g. derive reversable relations, aggregate relations (e.g. 3 persons are related to John), classify into types of relations (family relations, work relations, ...), and this all based on user generated input and not a (known) predefined set of relations.

Comment: @LaundroMat: If you want to expand your question, please **update** your question.  Multi-party relationships are not part of the question as asked above.  They're trivial, BTW, since the essential "RelatedTo" can contain many "Parties".   My answer does not include any predefined set of relationships.  The relationship field is text, exactly as you requested.

Comment: (A bit late, but) I've updated my question - basically I'm looking for a relationship framework where I can easily derive meta-information out of.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I am not an expect.   I'm learning Django in my spare time.   That said..

You may want to look at the "many to many **through**" as a field relationship.

From the docs:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

> When you're only dealing with simple
>   many-to-many relationships such as
>   mixing and matching pizzas and
>   toppings, a standard ManyToManyField
>   is all you need. **However, sometimes
>   you may need to associate data with
>   the relationship between two models.**

Where the syntax look like this (also from the example in the docs):

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```